# I'm getting an error as NaN in the code for reversing the number. Why?

Tags: javascript, html

This is the code I typed to find the reverse of a number which is entered in a textbox named "txt" and form name is "calc2". I'm not able to figure out the problem.

```
function rev() {
    var n, rn, r;
    n = parseInt(calc2.txt.value);
    rn = 0;
    while(n!==0) {
        rn = rn * 10;
        rn = rn + r % 10;
        n = n / 10;
    }
    calc2.ans.value = rn;
}
```

Chrome shows the following warning :

```
calc2.js:62 The specified value "NaN" is not a valid number.
The value must match to the following regular expression:
  -?(\d+|\d+\.\d+|\.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?rev
    @ calc2.js:62onclick
    @ home.html?txt=511:54
```

Comment: what's line 62?

Comment: `rn = rn + r % 10;` - `r` is never defined.

Comment: It looks like that `r` is a typo, and should be `n`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this

```
function rev() {
    var n, rn;
    n = parseInt(calc2.txt.value);
    rn = 0;
    while(n!==0) {
        rn = rn * 10;
        rn = parseInt(rn + n % 10, 10);
        n = parseInt(n / 10, 10);
    }
    calc2.ans.value = rn;
}
```

Working example https://jsfiddle.net/pff7vw6x/

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot. Can you explain the code ?